# How to boot from local disk using grub2 during a PXE boot

Tags: boot, uefi, grub2, pxe

I have a working BIOS-based PXE boot setup that I established years ago on a Linux CentOS 7 server. In the `pxelinux.cfg/default` file, I have the following lines (among other menu entries):

```
LABEL local
      MENU LABEL Boot local hard drive
      text help
          Boot the system from the hard drive set in the BIOS
      endtext
      LOCALBOOT 0
```

It appears that my pxelinux.0 file still uses an older version of grub. The `LOCALBOOT` will simply continue the boot from the local hard drive, whether that system is CentOS, Ubuntu, Windows, etc.

I've recently expanded my dhcpd/bootp/PXE setup to include UEFI, following [directions](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/pxe-boot-uefi) from Redhat. However, `grubx64.efi` can't interpret the the old-style grub format; the UEFI PXE process apparently expects a `grub.cfg` that uses the more recent grub2 syntax.

Using grub2, I can easily set up menuentry options for installing Linux and other OSes. What I can't figure out, despite scouring the [grub2 documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html), is how to set up a simple "just boot the local drive" option.

I've tried things like:

```
menuentry 'Boot local drive' 
    exit
}
```

But that reboots the system which, if I'd set it up for network boot, just invokes PXE again. I tried using `bootlocal`, `local`, `boot`, `localboot` instead of `exit`, but either I get a message about an unrecognized command or (in the case of `boot`) about no kernel being available.

Is this even possible in grub2? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite the same but makes it possible to boot from a local disk:

```
menuentry "Local Disk" {
        insmod chain
        search --set=root --file /EFI/centos/grubx64.efi
        chainloader /EFI/centos/grubx64.efi
}
```

Notice that the path to `grubx64.efi` unfortunately depends on the OS installed. I first saw this tip at https://github.com/quattor/aii/issues/216.

Answer (score 0):

Solution by Flippe Maia works fine, but you have to know the path to `grubx64.efi`. But you can boot from second boot device if you just exit from grub.

```
menuentry 'Local Boot' {
exit
}
```

Ofcourse  it will now depend on your bios configuration

Comment: If you look towards the end of my original post, you'll see that I tried exactly that solution.

However, that's not what I'm looking for. I want to set up a grub2 menu such that I can leave the EFI machine on network boot. Then, if no one touches the console for some some time interval (let's say two minutes), then machine will boot up from disk. 

It's easy to do this with a generic BIOS-based system, but (as previously noted) it's not universal: I have to know the location of grubx64.efi for each EFI system on my cluster... and set up a separate PXE/grub2 config for each.

Comment: My bad, i haven't noticed paragraph about exit. In my case, `exit` just exits bootloader without reboot and boot continue with next option, in my case its first disk. Maybe there are something with your boot order? What will happen if your pxe server is unreachable?